# Status Code for RedirectResults is 200 and not 302 when calling from server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-codes

I'm trying to get Redirect status 301 when calling an external api using HttpClient.SendAsync(request).
The status of the response for that call is 200 and not 302 as expected for RedirectResults.

The call from the server is

```
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
var status = response.StatusCode; //StatusCode is 200 and not 301
```

The api returns:

```
return Redirect(url);
```

Any idea why the response status is 200 and not 302?
Thanks

Comment: So the issue is to pass HttpClientHandler with AllowAutoRedirect = false, how can I achieve it using IHttpClientFactory.CreateClient? thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I added this

```
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler
{
    AllowAutoRedirect = false
});
```

woeking :)